# Copying large MSI files quickly using natural Windows 7 features

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, cmd.exe

I'm creating some batch scripts for work that are used to install applications for end users, these scripts rely heavily on a network share we call `mgtutils`, this share is of course slow, and what has to be done is, the files have to be copied to the users desktop and executed from there. The copying is what takes the longest, this aspect of the scripts can take as long as 5 minutes to copy an `MSI` file over to the users desktop.

I've looked at `robocopy` but that appears to be used more for multiple files then a single file. As of now I'm using `xcopy` I know it probably has a lot to do with the fact that the drive is so slow, but is there a different built in command within Windows 7 to quickly copy files?

Comment: The first step would be to find the bottleneck, not look for alternative commands. No command will copy the file faster if the speed is limited by 
 eg. network throughput.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm about 90% sure that the bottle neck is the shared drive itself

Comment: No other command will help you then. No algorithm or protocol can store data before it's read, you can't write bytes from the future. You don't fix the bottleneck by fiddling with non-bottlenecks.